# Configuring Jersey to provide a WADL through JSON

Tags: java, jersey, wadl

So Jersey's default WADL functionality is great! Except if your developing your API to only handle JSON at which point it seems a little silly to force your client apps to switch back to XML for the WADL.

Could anyone provide (or point me to) an example of how to get Jersey to produce a JSON representation of the WADL document?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a patch for Jersey now

[Jersey JSON WADL patch](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-638)